# URLSession request no longer accepted by server

Tags: json, swift3, xcode8, ios10

After reviewing and trying other questions and answers on StackOverflow I continue to have the following issue.

The app is meant to verify a user's username and password, then log them into the server on another screen provided the server authenticated that the user and password are valid.

The JSON response is meant to have a key **Success** and if it's a **1** then ok to log on else if **0** the user can not log on.

Worked fine with Swift 2 and I performed the recommended changes moving from Swift2 to Swift 3 and have no errors but have a strange response to the following code.

```
            let body : String = ("username=\(tkUserName.text!)&password=\(tkPassword.text!)")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/LoginApp")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
        { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                    if response == nil
                    {
                        //advise user no internet or other
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var success : Int?
                        do {
                            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                            success = jsonResult!.object(forKey: "success") as? Int

                        }
                        catch let error as NSError
                        {
                            //action error
                        }

                        if success == 1
                        {
                            //capture all is good and go to other page                                
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindThenGoToTeamPage", sender: self)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //THIS IS WHERE IT DROPS INTO EACH TIME AS SUCCESS WAS "0"

                        }
                    }

            }.resume()
```

Here is the server response

```
    Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 7/02/2017 10:19:31 AM
Event time (UTC): 6/02/2017 11:19:31 PM
Event ID: 1f9ff75ee64149b0994fa4a46a6ea03b
Event sequence: 5
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0
```

and

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7b9ea440> { URL: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/teambeta/LoginApp } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 67;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 08 Feb 2017 03:48:09 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"Set-Cookie" = "ASP.NET_SessionId=ixxxxxxxxxxx; domain=xxxxx.com; path=/; HttpOnly, .ASPXAUTH=xxxxxxxxxxx; domain=xxxxx.com; expires=Fri, 10-Mar-2017 17:08:09 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, TIsMobileDevice=True; path=/";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-AspNetMvc-Version" = "5.2";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
```

} }

There is a lot more the server responded with but the issue seems to be with the URL Session I am creating.   The JSON serialization is working fine but no Success key so I am not giving the server correct URL data.

And I checked that the server is still working fine for Swift2 as well as the Android and Windows versions so I know it's my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code, this is working fine at my end. Pls check:

```
 var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(AUTENTICATION_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "AuthenticateKey")

    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
    request.timeoutInterval = 30
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else
        {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }

        do
        {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
            completion(json)
        }
        catch let parseError
        {
            print(parseError)
            // Log the error thrown by `JSONObjectWithData`
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("Error could not parse JSON to load staff: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }) 
    task.resume()
```

Comment: for some reason question got marked down but no idea why,  will keep working on it.  thanks for input but no help as tried that already.